# "SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'" when I used jsonp to cross domain in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, jsonp

I used laravel5.2 in my project;

javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: 'http://XX.XX.XX.XX/account/status?callback=?',
    dataType : 'jsonp',
    contentType: "application/json",
    jsonp : "callback",
    jsonpCallback: "jsonpcallback",
    success: function(data){
          console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(){
        alert('500 error!')
    }
});
```

route:

```
Route::get('/account/status', 'HomeController@accountStatus');
```

controller:

```
public function accountStatus(Request $request)
{
    return  Response::json(array('name' => 'Steve', 'state' => 'CA'))->setCallback($request->input('callback'));
}
```

but the response information has the whole html file, it turns out my route in route.php doesn't work,because whatever I changed the request url, it returns the same error and shows:

> SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

[image]

Comment: `jsonp` has nothing do with this, You've `<` this somewhere on the `view` file. Search for it.

Comment: This could be a fail attempt to parse php error as json.

Comment: What do you see when you try to load `http://XX.XX.XX.XX/account/status?callback=?` directly in your browser? Is a Laravel error page displayed?

Comment: @DavidSmith, is  index.php page

Comment: @Alok, just html tag '<'

Comment: @FirstOne,so what do I need to do? it return a page

Comment: Well, you have to fix the php code first. Make sure that it's working correctly with no errors, then you move on. Try accessing the page directly from your browser (as suggested by @DavidSmith 11h ago).

Comment: @FirstOne, the page can load with no errors

Comment: It's late, and I can't debug your code for you. Try installing something like postman for chrome and simulate exactly the same request as you do in js. That should be a good start...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and suggestion.I'll try